# Using Presto with Azure Kubernetes (AKS)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, presto

I'm very new to Presto and I have Azure Kubernetes cluster and I'm trying to use Presto with it, doesn't seem to find any helpful tutorials for running Presto on AKS so I'm wondering if anyone can help me how to get started on this and if there is a simple step by step tutorial for beginners.

Comment: Checkout [trino](https://trino.io/episodes/31.html) if you are open to option.

Comment: to run Presto on kubernetes check out https://ahana.io/blog/presto-on-kubernetes/ and you can use the same to run on AKS with few modifications.